# How to integrate JS frameworks with django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm newbie to django. I use django forms to render HTML forms.

I would like to replace default ChoiceField with the popular JS framework "Select2" http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/.

I know it is easy to do so on the HTML pages directly, but i find it is hard to integrate it into django forms design. Maybe some 3rd party django plugin works as https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2, but when i add one more JS frameworks, i may need more and more 3rd party django plugins.

So what is the correct way to go with django forms? And why django take the HTML forms outside of HTML pages? As in Java, all HTML elements will go in JSP pages.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this simply by adding the `<script>` and `<style>` tags required by [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) in a `{% block extra_header %}` inside the template where the form is rendered. Those script tags should load the [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) library and run it for the select box directly in the client side (no server side changes are required IMHO). Any DOM changes that may be required should also be done in those scripts (this keeps the new feature encapsulated and isolated).

The `{% block extra_header %}` should load directly into the `<header>` section of the main template.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom widget and attach it to the ChoiceField.
That's not a 1-liner but looks like someone has made it easy for you. Take a look at this:

[select2 with django choicefield](https://bitbucket.org/slafs/django-selectable-select2/src/a4f21cf60d6e?at=default)

Comment: https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2 should work with this case. But when i add more JS frameworks,i must add more such libraries? I don't think this is an elegant way.

Comment: You could look at how they did it and use the same methodology. Basically, create a django widget using select2.

Comment: This way i need to write one widget for each new JS framework?